# What needs to be done to refactor a kotlin data class to an open class without affecting serialization?

Tags: kotlin

I have a kotlin data class that now needs to be used as a request scoped field in a controller - but Spring cannot proxy this (scoped fields are proxied by default). This class is also used as DTO in a REST controller. What do I need to do to the class so that the changes would be minimal to the classes using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you might need to install the kotlin-spring compiler plugin:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/all-open-plugin.html#spring-support.

As the doco says, it will support the main meta annotations, so you would likely need to add an "@Component" to your data class.